# When I tried to put in a new product key for my MS Office 2016 I misskeyed something and the default was to MS 365

Tags: microsoft-office

I have been using MS 2016 Office Pro 64bit and was asked to provide the product key to continue using it. When I tried to put in the key MS would not accept it. When I tried to back out of the box requesting the product key, I must have hit an incorrect key and inadvertently downloaded MS 365. I don't want MS 365, I want to continue using my MS 2016. How can I get my 2016 back?

Comment: Let me ask you a question.  Do you have an Office 365 subscription linked to your Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 1):

Your Office 2016 version has been converted to Office 365,
so is lost.

You'll have to completely remove Office 365 and install
Office 2016, then activate it again with your serial key.

If you don't have your original Office 2016 installation ISO/DVD,
you can still download the Office installer from:

- Your Microsoft Account page, section "Service & subscriptions"
  (if your Office version is linked to your Microsoft Account)
- Use the "Microsoft Windows and Office ISO Download Tool" from
  [HeiDoc.net](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-ISO-download-tool).
  This program downloads original Windows and Office ISO disk images
  directly from Microsoft and is updated regularly.

  [image]

Comment: Its easier to go to office.com/setup login with a microsoft account that has the license attached to it or create a new account and enter the license code in there. Then you can download a setup file that downloads all necessary files, just like the Microsoft 365 version.

Answer (score 0):

> > When I tried to put in the key MS would not accept it. When I tried to back out of the box requesting the product key,

Can you tell us What interface did you enter the key on?

For Office Professioanl 2016, it is a retail version of Office which needs you **redeem the Office key first**.

***I suggest you uninstall Microsoft 365 Apps first.***

To redeem this key go to **[setup.office.com](https://setup.office.com/)** and sign in with an existing Microsoft account or create a new one.

For more deatils, please refer to "[Get help with setup.office.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-help-with-setup-office-com-6e1bc8e8-9e8e-4cce-8b9d-80dcbe17f253#ID0EBBT=2019,_2016,_2013,_Visio,_Project,_Office_apps)".

Once the key is successfully redeemed, your Office license is bound to your Microsoft account. If you need to download Office, you can go to **[Subscriptions & Services](https://account.microsoft.com/services?refd=login.microsoftonline.com)** page.